# How to convert the output of select to list in eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In the following query:

```php
$search = 'boo';
MyModel::select('id', 'title')->where('title', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')->get();
```

I want to get the following output:

```php
[
    1 => 'book',
    4 => 'booth'
]
```

I tried the following, but it didn't' work:

```php
$search = 'boo';
MyModel::lists('id', 'title')->where('title', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')->get();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the `pluck()` function.
try:

```
MyModel::where('title', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')->pluck('title', 'id');
```

More details at https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#retrieving-results